# using cython to port modules to python 3.1

Tags: python, c, module, numpy, cython

Is it possible to import arbitrary modules in cython, compile them to shared object files and then use them in python 3.1?

The reason for this is, that I am writing an extension for the program "blender", which has an internal python 3.1 interpreter. But i would also like to make use of some python-modules which are not ported to 3.x, yet

I have specifically numpy in my mind (but also some other libraries). I have a module, which makes use of numpy. As I want to redistribute that module, I don't want poeple to install numpy on their machines. would that work?

Comment: Cython is for writing CPython extension modules, not for making applications standalone. Use [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/) for that. Also, what has this to do with Python 3 specifically?

Comment: I can not use cx_Freeze, as I just want to redistribute the module, together with an embedded python version. not an executable.

Comment: ohh I forgot:   that application which has an internal python interpreter uses python 3.1 (its blender (www.blenderorg)). some libraries are only available in python 2.xx  so it would be cool to make them available to python 3 by compiling them...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In principle, I believe it's possible. Cython works by translating Python-like code to C code. That code can be compiled for either Python 2 or Python 3 (it uses C preprocessor statements to change which code is used).

The bad news is that it will only work for extensions written in Python-like code that Cython can translate. You can't use Cython on extensions written in C, like Numpy.

The good news is that, at least for Numpy, you shouldn't have to. Since [version 1.5](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/release/1.5.0-notes.rst), Numpy supports Python 3. There's a binary available for Windows; on other systems, you might have to work out how to compile the code yourself.

Answer (score -2):

Check your Python documentation, the section "Python/C API Reference Manual" describes in detail how to do it.

**EDITED:**
So what you want is porting a 2.x lib to 3.x. That's a big work to do.
If the solution your wished exists. Python 2.x should have been eliminated by now.
Sure there is a 2to3 tool. But a Python lib written by C is not applicable in this way.

So, you may follow the instruction in the "Python/C API Reference Manual" to port the lib to 3.x or just wait.